# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'decode' on 'TextDecoder': The provided value is not of type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I am trying to decode some strings and am having trouble with this, looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder) I cannot see where I am going wrong.

```
var decoder = new TextDecoder('iso-8859-11')
decoder.decode("Moretó Font")    

VM2410:3 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'decode' on 'TextDecoder': The provided value is not of type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'
    at <anonymous>:3:26
```

Comment: https://javascript.info/text-decoder

Comment: So actually I am not using it in any kind of way that is correct or as it was intended. Thank you

Comment: "*I am trying to decode some strings*" - not sure what you mean by that. [`decode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/decode) takes a buffer.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi I thought with the example it was clear. I have the following string I would like to encode in utf-8 Moretó Font

Comment: Then don't use a decoder but an encoder, and don't use `iso-8859-11` but `utf-8` as the encoding.

Comment: Ye, the encoder makes sense, however I cannot see encoder as a property of `decoder`.

Comment: I mean use a [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) instead of the `TextDecoder`